# Disable/Remove images and link from loading in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I disable images and links from loading in HTML using a script.

```
<div id="mailPreviewTarget" style="padding: 10px; overflow: auto;">

    Sample Text
    <p></p>

    <img src="http://.../track/0/0.png">
    <div>

        <a href="http://.../unsubscribe/0/0">Unsubscribe</a>

    </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ks8r3noa/2/

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: use this  `$('.img, .a').css({'display','none'})`

Comment: `$('img').prop('src','#');` ?

Comment: Do you want the linked text to be unlinked? Or removed with the link?

Comment: You can't do this work becase when javascript is runned, image was loaded. You should remove it on server.

Comment: Just change the markup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent images from loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667868/prevent-images-from-loading)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js">
$(window).load(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
$('img , a').remove();  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(e){
$('img').css({'display':'none'});
$('a').css({'display':'none'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. Can you as well check it on jsfiddle?

Comment: This I'll never work. It will prevent rendering, but not loading.

Comment: am just define the event only @Mic, the problem is `,`  `:`

Comment: @mac now try  on this link http://jsbin.com/jekoyal/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @KarthikeyanSekar  you're a lifesaver! It really worked for me :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this type of code to disable the images and links.

```
    <script>
    function buttonClicked()
    {
       document.getElementById('buttonId').disabled = true;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I tried it on Jsfiddle but to no avail. Can you check it yourself as well. Thanks.

Comment: To disable link you can follow, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11901020/1246467. It works fine with Jsfiddle. You can use disableLink() function to achieve your task.

Comment: If you want to disable the image, you have to put it inside a <a> tag. `<a id="buttonId" href><img id="buttonImage" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-person-128.png"></a>`. Then you can use the answer. It works fine in Jsfiddle.